# how to enable deliverability testing from a non-administrator?

Tags: email, administration

How can I enable a non-administrator user to use the email deliverability test tool? I have checked the system permissions for the user profile and there is nothing listed that enables this functionality.

Comment: Does the user have the permission "Modify All Data"? That permission is needed to test email deliverability.

Comment: that's it, they didn't have that feature enabled.

Comment: do you want to put that in as the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A user has to have the "Modify All Data" permission is needed to test email deliverability as described [here](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_test_email_delivery.htm).